# Can't use Laravel's Authentification

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, overriding

I'm trying to configure the laravel's auth to fit with my db.
But whatever I do, override properties like `protected $table='my_table';` or `public function username() { return 'email_user'}` in LoginController, it ignore everything.
Does anyone know how to parameter the auth of laravel with different database ?

Here is what I changed in LoginController:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'email_user';
}
```

And in the User model :

```
protected $table = "pays";
protected $primaryKey = "id_user";

public function getAuthPassword() { 
    return $this->password_user; 
}

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name_user', 'surname_user', 'email_user', 'password_user', 'sex_user', 'birth_user', 'address_user', 
    'city_user', 'pc_user', 'phone_user', 'pic_user', 'status_user', 'license_user', 'urssaf_user', 
    'remember_token', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
];
```

EDIT : config/auth.php :

```
<?php

return [

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],




'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

];
 LoginController :

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function username()
{
    return 'email_user';
}
}
```

Comment: Post your config/auth.php file

Comment: Here's the link to download it https://mega.nz/#!AQUCDY6a!hqAXUnjm-Q0JFSCE2l8d81Uq18Jklt7SKBmTEzHKjA0

Comment: Please post it in your question

Comment: what is in your login controller

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta original file + public function username()
    {
        return 'email_user';
    }

Comment: I know but can you show your controller and error you are getting in login

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta I'm not getting erro when I try to login. I updated my post for LoginController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your login form keep password field with `name=password`:

```
<input type="text" name="email_user">

<input type="password" name="password">
```

Comment: that's already like that. I didn't touch the view. I only changed the RegisterController Login Controller and User

Comment: If you didn't touch the view, then your should change email field to 'email_user' as in LoginController. I have updated my answer.

Comment: omg, I'm so sorry, I haven't understand that way... That worked finally. Thank you so much and sorry for the inconvenience.